# How to extract dynamic values with jmeter Regular expression extractor?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, regex

Please let me know how to fetch the ID from the html using a regular expression & find the below expression i have used but am getting error response only.

Response Body:

```
"input type="hidden" name="paymentId" value='234201921134768136' "
```

Regular Expression:

```
input type="hidden" name="paymentId" value="(.+?)"
```

Variable name : `paymentId`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use regular expressions for this, here you go:

```
input type="hidden" name="paymentId" value="(\d+)"
```

Demo (assumes RegExp Tester more of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener):

[image]

However be informed that [using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) as regular expressions are very sensitive to markup changes and extra space or line break will ruin your regex.

Consider going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/) instead, it allows using [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for querying the document which is way more readable, robust and reliable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [CSS JQuery Extractor](https://home.apache.org/~milamber/jmeter-3.1RC3/docs/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor):

[image]

On CSS/JQuery Expression you locate HTML node and on Attribute you will extract the value of a given attribute (*name* in your case).

Comment: Thanks...Actually the payment id dynamically change for every user...so  CSS/JQuery Expression  would be applicable for this? can you confirm this???

Comment: It is a post-processor, meaning that the flow of execution will be directed to the following ThreadGroup (TG). If you want, e.g., make a GET to the payments service, you will have the value of payment id to be used. On the following user, the two (TG) will be run in this order as well. 
User 1: TG1 -> Post-Processor -> TG2
User 2: TG1 -> Post-Processor -> TG2
Never intertwined. You can have more info here: https://www.guru99.com/processor-in-jmeter.html

Comment: I am accessing external sites using company proxy server due to this i am unable to record those sites using jmeter. Can you help me on this issue.